# MS Access DSUM issue

Tags: ms-access

I have a text box in a form that sums up an "encumbered" column with the where condition matches the ID number in that table and the ID shown in the form. I get a #Name error but all of the naming is correct.

`=DSum("EncAmount",[tblEncumbrances],"[BID]='" & [frmProcurementEdit]![BudgetItemID] & "''")`

tblEncumbrances is the table name, EncAmount is the column whose sum I need to add up. FrmProcurementEdit is the form that the textbox is on and BudgetItemID (Also on the form) needs to match BID(In tblEncumbrances)

Am I missing something here? Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: Table name must be within quote marks. Also, looks like two closing apostrophe delimiters.

Comment: The form name prefix is not needed but shouldn't hurt.

Comment: @June7 I added the quotation marks to tblEncumbrances. Could the issue be that BudgetItemId is a text field while BID is not?

Comment: Why use DSum() and not Sum()? Edit question to show sample of data displayed on form.

Comment: You have used two single quote ending of formula. Make it one. Try- `=DSum("[EncAmount]","[tblEncumbrances]","[BID]='" & [frmProcurementEdit]![BudgetItemID] & "'")`

Comment: Yes, different data type would be an issue. Why are these linking fields different data types?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The literal table name must be enclosed in quote marks. Also, there is an extra closing apostrophe delimiter.

According to your comment, linking fields are not same data type. This will definitely be an issue and really should correct data structure. However, it can be dealt with. Assuming BID is an integer number:

`=DSum("EncAmount", "[tblEncumbrances]", "[BID]=" & CInt([BudgetItemID]))`

or

`=DSum("EncAmount", "[tblEncumbrances]", "[BID]=" & Val([BudgetItemID]))`

Answer (score -1):

=DSum("[EncAmount]","tblEncumbrances","[BID]='" & [BudgetItemID] & "'")